# How to build HTML to contain the output during a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop that I need to modify so that after a count of 10 it closes the html structure it's looping in and opens a new structure in order to add 10 more counts and so on until there are no more elements in the array.

```
<?php
// open the ul
$location_lists .= '<ul';

// get the array
$locations = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'location',
'showposts' => -1
));

foreach ($locations as $location) {
  $address = some code here;      
  $location_lists .= '<li>';
  $location_lists .= '<span>'. ($address) .'</span>';
  $location_lists .= '</li>';
};

// after 10 loops close the ul
$location_lists .= '</ul>';

// open a new ul to hold 10 more li's etc...
$location_lists .= '<ul';
?>
```

So, if there are 24 elements in the array, I need 2 ul's containing 10 li's each and the 3rd ul will contain the 4 remaining li's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$location_lists .= '<ul>';
$i=0;
foreach ($locations as $location) {
  $i++;
  $address = some code here;    
  $location_lists .= '<li>';
  $location_lists .= '<span>'. ($address) .'</span>';
  $location_lists .= '</li>';

  if (($i % 10) == 0) {
       $location_lists .= '</ul><ul>';
  }
};
$location_lists .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: This code did exactly what I was asking for in my question. It's very clean and concise.

Comment: Just discovered a problem. This script will create an additional empty ul if there are exactly ten elements in the array.

Comment: This works -
if ( ($i % 10) == 1 && $i > 10 ) {
@DeveloperH

Answer (score 1):

```
    $location_lists='';
$locations = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'location',
'showposts' => -1
));
$i=0;
foreach ($locations as $location) {
  if($i==0){$location_lists .= '<ul>';}
  $address = some code here;      
  $location_lists .= '<li>';
  $location_lists .= '<span>'. ($address) .'</span>';
  $location_lists .= '</li>';
  $i++;
 if($i==10){$location_lists .= '</ul>';$i=0}
};
if($i!=0){$location_lists .= '</ul>';}
```

Comment: Out of 92 available elements in 6 categories, this code only output the last category of 19 elements in the array. One UL containing 10 elements and the second containing 9.